# I have a Dell Inspiron 15 5559 with a cracked screen. How can I change settings in the BIOS without being able to read the screen?

Tags: boot, laptop, bios

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 5559 with a cracked screen. How can I change settings in the BIOS without being able to read the screen? I want to install Windows 7 Ultimate but cant change the boot order because the left half of the screen is shattered. An external display is no good since the BIOS cant access the video drivers. I would list the BIOS version but I can't see that either.

Comment: Why no external monitor? bios is usually basic, like 640x480

Answer (score 0):

1. Fix the screen. You can contact Dell to find your local service center, or use your favourite repair center
2. Now that you can use the computer properly, try installing Windows.